# Processing sketches have stopped working in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, processing, cloudflare

I just noticed this yesterday. My processing sketches on willhay.io have stopped working in Google Chrome and Firefox, however, they work fine in Safari. I haven't changed their code so it is very strange. Console is giving me this error

```
GET http://willhay.io/cdn-cgi/pe/bag2? r[]=http%3A%2F%2Fwillhay.io%2Fprocessing%2Fprocessing.min.js 405 (Not Allowed)
```

Something to do with Cloudflare maybe (I've just got the free version)? Check it out for yourself here:
http://willhay.io/processing/trip/

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was CloudFlare and the way their RocketLoader page speed optimizer works. I just turned it off after remembering I switched it on the other day and the Processing sketches are now working fine. Had something to do with the way it messes with the javascript and I guess processing.js didn't like that.